# Условие - если текущая категория не верхняя

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть следующий код:

```
<?php 
$i=1;
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categories = get_categories('parent='.$cat.''); 
foreach ($categories as $category) { $i++; }
if ($i > 1) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } 
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    $pcat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
    $pcatid = $pcat->category_parent;
    $categories = get_categories('parent='.$pcatid.''); 
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <li<?php if ($category->term_id == $cat) { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } 
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Он выводит список подкатегорий текущей категории. Но если у текущей категории нету подкатегорий то выводятся подкатегории к той категории, что выше текущей по иерархии.

Т.е. если мы находимся по адресу сайт.ру/верхняя_категория  то выводится просто список категорий сайта (если подкатегорий у текущей категории нет). Это мне и надо убрать.

Но если мы находимся по адресу  сайт.ру/верхняя_категория/подкатегория и в ней нету ещё своих подкаегорий то должны выводится дочерные категории для сайт.ру/верхняя_категория/ (т.е. тут все должно работать как сейчас)

Comment: Приведите таблицу категорий ,как вы их храните (категории,подкатегории и т п ) ? Я сильно сомневаюсь что вы можете это реализовать без рекурсии

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan в смысле, как я их храню? Стандартные категории вордпресса со стандартной иерархией

Comment: в смысле как выглядит ваша таблица для хранения категорий и их подкатегорий.если это одна таблица с parent_id , где parent_id указывает на его родителя ,то тут дерево можно получить только с помощью рекурсии.

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan есть таблица `wp_terms` - она содержит категории, теги и ссылки. И есть таблица `wp_term_taxonomy` - связывает между собой категории, ссылки блогролла и теги воедино, а также устанавливает очередность и вложенность категорий (рубрик)

Comment: На такой вопрос и информацию только такой ответ http://stackoverflow.com/a/18409050/6120970
посмотри в других ответах ,или поищи аналогичным способом

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте:

```
     $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'child_of'                 => 0,
            'parent'                   => 0,
            'orderby'                  => 'name',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'               => 1,
            'hierarchical'             => 0,
            'exclude'                  => '',
            'include'                  => '',
            'number'                   => '',
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
            'pad_counts'               => false 
            );
            $cats = get_categories( $args );
            foreach( $cats as $cat) {
                if($cat->parent == 0) {
                    $parent_cat = null;
                    $head = $cat->name;
                    $head_id = $cat->term_id;
                }
                echo "<ul><a class='parent-category' href=''>" . $head . "</a>";                                                    
                wp_list_cats("sort_column=NAME&optioncount=0&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&child_of={$head_id}&show_option_none=");
                echo "</ul>";
            }
```